# How to mock Context without the @Mock annotation

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

I'm currently refactoring unit tests and I'm trying to use
`import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.mock` as much as possible.

I was trying to mock Context like this
`private val context = mock<Context>`

However, it's throwing this exceptions:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked.`

My suspicion is that Context cannot be mocked this way `private val context = mock<Context>` and that it cannot be mocked without the @Mock annotation.

Before, Context was mocked like this:

```
@Mock
lateinit var context: Context
```

Is my suspicion correct? and if so, could I please get an explanation as to why it can't be mocked that way? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MockContext`. Official documentation here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext

```
private lateinit var mockContext: MockContext

@Before
fun setUp() {
   mockContext = MockContext()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. This worked for me:

```
    context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
```

Note: only works in the androidTest folder.